# How to create mlir constant vector using OpBuilder

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

MLIR allows create constant vector such as

```
%1 = arith.constant dense<[1.1 2.2 3.3]> : vector<3xf32>
```

But how can I create this mlir operation using OpBuilder?
I tried using codes like this

```
builder.create<arith::ConstantOp>(loc, builder.getDenseF32ArrayAttr(llvm::ArrayRef<float>{1.1, 2.2, 3.3}));
```

and then I found that arith::ConstantOp can only create scalar(int, float and index).

I want to know if there's a way to create constant vector using mlir class OpBuilder in c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
std::vector<float> x{1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
// builder is an OpBuilder
Value xVec = builder.create<arith::ConstantOp>(loc, DenseFPElementsAttr::get(VectorType::get(3, FloatType::getF32(builder.getContext())), ArrayRef<float>(x)));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).